# How to fill an outline font

Tags: fonts, webfonts

I am trying to use the font CC Biff Bam Boom Outline Regular for a web project.
(https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/cc-biff-bam-boom)

Is there any way to change the color of both the characters (outlines) and the inside of the characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
h1 { font-size: 4em;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px darkgrey;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
   -webkit-animation: fill 0.5s infinite alternate;}

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  from { -webkit-text-fill-color: steelblue; }
  to { -webkit-text-fill-color: slategrey; }
 }
```